# Cannot find EJB beanName on deploy

Tags: java, deployment, ejb-3.0

Hi @All :) I have a strange problem here. I want to inject `UserBean` managed entity in a class with the `@EJB(beanName="user")`. If I don't use the `beanName` attribute I get the following error message:

```
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: No component found for type 'defaultPackage.UserBean' with name null
```

If I use it like so `@EJB(beanName="user") UserBean user;` I get this:

```
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: No component found for type 'defaultPackage.UserBean' with name user
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the `UserBean` and how I inject it:

**UserBean**

```
// removed imports
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@Local
@SessionScoped
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class UserBean implements Serializable, UserInterface{
    // fields (@Columns, etc.)
    // setters / getters
}
```

**UserBeanUser**

```
// more removed imports
@ManagedBean(name="userUsed")
@Stateful
@Local
public class UserOfUserBean implements Serializable, Userable {

    private @EJB(beanName="user") UserBean user;
}
```

The interfaces are empty and are marked as `@Local`.

Comment: Now when I see this I say "You are idiot" to myself in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this is wrong on so many levels that it's hard where to begin.

To start, the `@Local` annotation is useless on the code you show. It's used to mark an interface as a business interface for an EJB, or point to such an interface.

Then, the entity `UserBean` should probably not be scoped and a managed bean. These annotations are for letting the bean container manage the life-cyle of a bean, but in case of an entity it's the entity manager that is responsible for that.

It's not clear whether you used the JSF or Java EE `ManagedBean` annotation here, but the latter is never needed and the first shouldn't be needed as per the above explanation.

Additionally, per the typical conventions consider naming an entity just `User` and don't let it implement an interface.

`UserOfUserBean` is even harder to decipher. Is this bean supposed to be a business service or a (JSF) backing bean? If it's a backing bean, you don't need the `@Stateful` annotation and otherwise you don't need the `@ManagedBean` one.

Then, the major culprit of your question: the @EJB annotation can't inject non-EJB beans. JPA entities (`@Entity`) and JSF managed beans (`@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`) are not EJB beans.

Furthermore, the `beanName` attribute of `@EJB` **does not** correspond to the `name` attribute in `@ManagedBean`. The bean name is an EJB internal thing used to disambiguate an injection if an interface is implemented by multiple beans and has no relation to either the JSF managed bean name or the Java EE managed bean name. *(not applicable to your question, but there is a relation between CDI's `@Named` and JSF's managed bean name)*

Finally, entities nor backing beans need empty interfaces that are marked as `@Local`.

So, your entity should become something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    // fields (@Columns, etc.)
    // setters / getters
}
```

And you should forget about injecting the entity the way you did. If you want to make it available in the HTTP session, put it there manually (e.g. after logging in). See this answer for a more elaborate explanation on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355064/472792

Assuming your `UserOfUserBean` was a backing bean, it would then become something like this with CDI:

```
@Named(name="userUsed")
public class UserOfUserBean {

    @Inject
    @LoggedIn // see answer from jan groth
    private User user;
}
```

or with JSF annotations only:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userUsed") // from javax.faces.bean, not javax.annotation
public class UserOfUserBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{user}") 
    private User user;

    // Mandatory setter for JSF-native injection
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Some additional resources:

- [Contexts and Dependency Injection in Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html)
- [How do CDI and EJB compare? interact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684112/how-do-cdi-and-ejb-compare-interact/4705840#4705840)

Comment: Very well, thank you for your hones and detailed answer. One more question to you: Can you give me some references to good book that I could read about EJB/JSF/CDI because I think I am a completely messed out with all that stuff.

Comment: You're welcome. I found the following books helpful for pure EJB theory: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0596158025 and http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1933988347 and the following for JSF: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0137012896 and http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0071625097 (the last one is in need of some errata though). Unfortunately there's nothing about CDI yet and even less about the intersection between those (Cay's book deals a little about CDI though). Supposedly http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0557078326 contains some of that, but I haven't time to read it yet so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much Arjan Tijms :)